# What can we say about maps that satisfy $|f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)|\leq C$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, banach-spaces

In going through Serge Lang's Undergraduate analysis, in the chapter on the inverse mapping theorem, we are asked to show that for any such function $f\: : E\to F$ where $E$ and $F$ are Banach spaces, with the property that $$|f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)|\leq C$$ for all $x,y\in E$  then there is a unique additive map $g$ such that $\sup(g-f)$ is bounded. This map can be shown to be $\lim \frac{f(2^n x)}{2^n}$ As follows:

*Proof.*
Let $f_n:E\to F$ be the sequence of functions such that $f_n(x)=\frac{f(2^n x)}{2^n}$. By our inequality,$$|f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)|=\left|\frac{f(2^{n+1} x)}{2^{n+1}}-2\left(\frac{f(2^n x)}{2^{n+1}}\right)\right|=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\left|f(2^{n+1} x)-2f(2^{n}x)\right|\leq \frac{C}{2^{n+1}}$$ Then we have $$
|f_{n+m}(x)-f_n(x)|\leq |f_{n+m}-f_{n+m-1}|+|f_{n+m-1}-f_{n+m-2}|+\cdots +|f_{n+1}-f_n|$$
$$\leq \frac{C}{2^{n+1}}\left|1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+2^{-m+1}\right|\leq \frac{C}{2^n}
$$
Then as $n\to \infty$, we have $\frac{C}{2^n}\to 0$ meaning that $f_n\to g$ uniformly, since $C$ doesn't depend on $x$. We can see that $f_0=f$ meaning that $$|f_m(x)-f|\leq C$$ for all $m$ meaning that since $f_n\to g$ we have $|g-f|\leq C$, and we have a bound on $g-f$. Since we have $$|f_n(x+y)-f_n(x)-f_n(y)|=\frac{1}{2^n}\left|f(2^n(x+y))-f(2^n x)-f(2^n y)\right|\leq \frac{C}{2^n}$$ then, when $n\to \infty$, $g(x+y)-g(x)-g(y)=0$ and hence $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$, meaning $g$ is additive.

Assume there are two functions $g_1,g_2$ such that $|g_1-f|\leq C$ and $|g_2-f|\leq C$. then we have $$|g_1-g_2|=|g_1-f+f-g_2|\leq |g_1-f|+|g_2-f|\leq 2C$$ This means that $g_1-g_2$ is bounded. Let $q=g_1-g_2$ then we have $q(x+y)=g_1(x+y)-g_2(x+y)=g_1(x)+g_1(y)-g_2(x)-g_2(y)=q(x)+q(y)$ meaning that $g_1-g_2$ is also an additive function. Since we have $q(nx)=\sum_n q(x)=nq(x)$ the only way for $q$ to be bounded is for $q$ to be identically zero, meaning $g_1=g_2$, hence $g$ is unique.

**Question** : Requiring $f$ to be continuous means that $g$ is continuous and linear. My question is, what are some good examples of such a map. If we take $f$ to be bounded, then $g$ just ends up being $0$, are there better examples where $g$ ends up being more interesting? and what information does $g$ give us about our function $f$, since given $g$ there is not a unique such $f$ satisfying $\lim f_n =g$.

Comment: You can get examples by starting with any linear map $g$ and adding any bounded function.

Comment: @RobertIsrael This is true, but I don't think it's all that interesting, since in the limit, the bounded term goes to zero and the $g$ just goes directly to $g$. I'd like to see if there are any non-trivial examples to this.

Comment: Why does the bounded term have to go to $0$?